# Using Axios to get a name from a site

Tags: reactjs, json, ajax, axios

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import axios from "axios";

const BASEURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";


function axiosTest() {
    return axios.get(BASEURL).then(response => response.data[0].name)
}

function Component1(){

console.log(axiosTest());
}



const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Component1 />);
```

This is my code, I'm trying to extract data from this URL with axios.  I am *this* close to accomplishing my goal.  Here's what the console prints out.
[image]

My question is, what do I do I if to get the console to solely print out "Leanne Graham"?  I've tried putting ".resolve()" after "name", but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axio returns an asynchronous call that need to resolve in order to access the data. So use the `then` to wait till the call is resolved.

```
function Component1(){
     axiosTest()
        .then(data =>{
           console.log(data)
        })
}
```